# How do I loop through results and display day of the week once at every change in day using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

with my current query and loop:

```
$sched = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM  `shows` 
ORDER BY  `shows`.`show_time` ASC")
or die(mysql_error());  


echo "<ul>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sched)){
echo "<li><a href=\"#$row[id]\">";
echo $row['title'];
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

This works great for displaying my results like this:

- Name of show 1
- Name of show 2
- Name of show 3

However, I want to add an item to the list at the beginning of every change in day so it would display as follows:

- Monday
- Name of show 1
- Name of show 2
- Tuesday
- Name of show 3
- Wednesday
- Name of show 4

I can't quite wrap my brain around the loop needed to do this. It might be helpful to know that the field 'show_time' is a datetime type, so it has the information for both time and day of week.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple tweak:

```
echo "<ul>";
$curDay='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sched)){
   $d=date('l',strtotime($row['show_time']));
   if($d!=$curDay){
     echo '<li>'.$d.'</li>';
   }
   $curDay=$d;
   echo '<li><a href="#',$row['id'],'">',$row['title'],"</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Initialize `$curDay`, and then each time through the loop, check to see if the particular day is different than the last time through the loop (or different from the initial value)

Comment: Also it'll make sense to change query to "SELECT id, title, DAYNAME(show_time) as show_time
FROM  `shows` 
ORDER BY  shows.show_time ASC"

Comment: This will not work sadly as the curdy variable would track both day and time (since the question states the time of day is included, so you would get a new time header for every Showtime, not every day.

Comment: @Simon `date('l',strtotime(DATE_TIME))` destroys all data except the day of the week.~

Comment: If you format it using DAYNAME() as I suggested it should work though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AR DAYNAME would be perfectly fine~ PHP's `strtotime` is also fine handling DATETIMES

Comment: @ar your version would work too, but would put the load onto the db server, which would work, t if say he wanted the actual value of the show time for display in the loop as well (eg after the name or something like that) he would have lost the detail, and would need the full field in the query as well, hence the client side formatting in my answer.

Comment: @Simon OP said, "...so it would display as follows: ", and I'm just going off of _that_ format

Comment: @Simon I think our messages passed each other as i was editing my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to keep a flag in your loop, and compare to the previous value.

Eg.

```
$previousDay = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($previousDay != date('l', $row['show_time'])) {
     echo '<h2>' . $date('l', $row['show_time']) . '</h2>';
  }
  ...
  $previousDay = date('l', $row['show_time']);
}
```

Comment: This can be optimised a bit by moving the date call to a variable in the loop scope, but it's painful enough coding on an iPad, so will hae to wait until tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your query to sort by `show_time` first.

```
"SELECT * FROM  `shows` ORDER BY `show_time`, `shows` ASC"
```

Then keep track of the current day as Shad suggests, parsing `show_time` to determine the day.